# Averaging between select varibles on an RLE list, having trouble with the last element

Tags: python, list, run-length-encoding

So I have created a compressed list using run length encoding. Now I'm attempting to find averages within certain variables in the list (e.g. `450` and `180`). The code should work like this

```
 a=[[180,3],[140,1],[160,1],[150,2],[450,1][180,4]]
 print mean(a)
 >[[180,3],[150,4],[450,1][180,4]]
```

I'm rather new at this otherwise I would have preformed the averaging during my compression.

What I'm stuck on are two things: my resulting list when uncompressed is not the same length of the original and I'm uncertain how append the last element should the code not pass through the last else. I could use indexing within my for loop with something like `elif i[0].index==len(lst)`, but that would be computationally expensive (the dataset is rather large). 
What I've created is a final if statement outside the for loop, but the resulting list is still not the same length as the original.

```
def mean(lst):
    sm=0
    count=0
    new=[]
    for i in lst:
        if i[0] is None:
            new.append([0,1])  
        elif i[0]!=180.0 and i[0]!=450.0:
           sm+=(i[0]*i[1])
           count+=i[1]
        elif count==0:
           new.append(i)      
        else:
            new.append([sm/count,count])
            new.append(i)
            count=0
            sm=0 
    if count>0:
        new.append([sm/count,count])
    pass    
    return (new)
```

And just for those who would research the problem later, I've added my solution which combined the compression and averaging. And to clarify the purpose, I'm compressing the angles between road segments in a GIS program to create a smaller data set. The 450's can be treated as Null values.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("test_loop",["angle3"]) as cursor:
    count1 = 0
    count2=0
    count3=0
    add=0
    lst=[]
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0]<180 and row[0] is not None:
            if count1>0:
                lst.append([180,count1+count3])
                count1=0
                count3=0
                pass    
            count2+=1
            add+=row[0]
        elif row[0]==180:
            if count2>0:
                lst.append([add/count2,count2+count3])
                count2=0
                count3=0
                add=0
                pass    
            count1+=1    
        elif row[0]==450 or row[0] is None:
            count3+=1
        else:
            print "Error"
            break   
    if count1>0:
        lst.append([180,count1+count3])
        count1=0
        count3=0
    elif count2>0:
        lst.append([add/count2,count2+count3])
        count2=0
        count3=0
        add=0  
    else:
        lst.append([None,count3])                      
    print lst
    del cursor
    del row

def decode(lst):
   q = []
   for i in lst:
       for x in range(i[1]):
           q.append (i[0])
   return q   

final=decode(lst)
print final               

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("test_loop",["curve_level"]) as cursor:
    i=0
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=final[i]
        i+=1
        cursor.updateRow(row)
del cursor
del row
```

Comment: not clear what you're expecting. You talk about lists of same length, but the desired results you show are a list of length == 4 from an input of len == 6.  **NB** you have an `else` statement which will *always* be evaluated if the preceding if/elif are not met. All `i` will be processed by the `if/elif/elif/else` block.

Comment: Sorry, length is defined as the addition of all i[1] in the list or the list once decoded.

Comment: OK then why does your example output (which presumably is what you *want* to receive) not match?  the i[1] sums to 12, versus 11 in the original input list.

Comment: Actually there is an error with the output list, before the last element it is missing a comma.

Comment: Should your output really be : `[[180,7],[150,4],[450,1]]`

Comment: Nope, the list order is extremely important.

Comment: OK it wasn't clear to me why you weren't grouping the "180" elements together (since you were grouping all the other non-180/non-450 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you shouldn't have duplicate entries of 180 in your output, and your expected output is:

```
[[180,7],[150,4],[450,1]]
```

I think this will do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def mean(lst):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    sm, count = 0.0, 0
    for [k, v] in lst:
        if float(k) in [180.0,450.0]:
            d[k] += v
        else:
            sm += k*v
            count +=v
    if sm != 0: d[sm/count] = count
    return [list(itm) for itm in d.items()]
```

Comment: I did solve the issue finally by combining the compression with the averaging.